# Python doesn't find packages that are installed with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda to `C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3`. When I type `conda list` it verifies that I have `BeautifulSoup4` installed.

However when I start `C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\python.exe` and try to import BeautifulSoup it doesn't work:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

When I'm in the Anaconda Navigator it also lists the package but when I try to start `base(root)/Open with python` I can't import my package. Neither can Spyder that I installed.
What do I have to do, to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm sorry but maybe you need to import in this way ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

[docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#)